# Integrability of Expression Involving Bounded Function on Unbounded Interval

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, continuity, improper-integrals, substitution

We have that $f:[1,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is bounded and continuous, and we would like to show that
$$\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_1^R\frac{f(t)}{t^2}\,\text{dt}$$
exists using the substitution rule.

Suppose $\lvert f\rvert\leq M$, $\forall x\in[1,\infty)$, then noting that continuous functions on compact sets are integrable, we can see

$$\Big{\lvert}\int_1^R\frac{f(t)}{t^2}\,\text{dt}\Big{\rvert}\leq
M\Big{\lvert}\int_1^R\frac{1}{t^2}\,\text{dt}\Big{\rvert}$$

and then apply the substitution $\phi=-\frac{1}{t}$ so that $\text{d}\phi=\frac{1}{t^2}\text{d}t$ giving

$$M\Big{\lvert}\int_1^R\frac{1}{t^2}\,\text{dt}\Big{\rvert}=
M\Big{\lvert}\int_{-1}^{-\frac{1}{R}}\text{dt}\Big{\rvert}=
M(1-\frac{1}{R})$$

however I don't think this shows the result, since we are looking at the modulus of the integral and the integral could bounce in $[-M,M]$ as $R$ increases.

Without using the boundedness,
$$\int_1^R\frac{f(t)}{t^2}\,\text{dt}=
\int_{-1}^{-\frac{1}{R}}f\Big(-\frac{1}{\phi}\Big)\text{dt}
$$
but I do not see how this could help.

I have tried some other similar substitutions but I can't seem to make progress with this. Any hints would be great!

Comment: Isn't the real goal to show that $\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_R^\infty \frac{f(t)}{t^2} \, dt = 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $ t\in (0,1] $, define

$$g(t)=f(\frac 1t)$$
$ f $ is bounded at $ [1,+\infty) \implies g $ is bounded at $ (0,1]$.

the substitution $ u=\frac 1t $, allows us to say the integrales
$$I=\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{f(t)}{t^2}dt $$
and
$$J=\int_0^1g(u)du $$
have the same nature.

Let $$M=\sup_{x\in(0,1]}|g(x)|$$
If we put, $ g(0)=M$, we prove easily that $ g $ is Riemann integrable at $ [0,1]$ and therefore

$$\lim_{r\to0^+}\int_r^{1}g(u)du\in \Bbb R$$
or
$$\lim_{R\to+\infty}\int_1^R\frac{f(t)dt}{t^2}\in \Bbb R$$